# Jinja SQL template for WHERE IN [elem1, elem2, ...]

Tags: sql, jinja2

I would like to use Jinja to parametrise SQL query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name IN ("a", "b", "c")
```

I would like to parametrise `("a", "b", "c")` using jinja so that I can pass a list `["a", "b", "c"]`. How can I do that? I found a possible way using Apache Superset `{{ filter_values(<list>)|where_in }}`. Is there a way to do it natively without using preset? Thanks

Comment: Why not a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the contents of such a list, so you need a loop e.g:

```
from jinja2 import Template

def generate_sql(names):
    template = Template("""
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE name IN (
        {%- for name in names %}
            "{{ name }}"
            {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
    )
    """)

    return template.render(names=names)

sql = generate_sql(["a", "b", "c"])
print(sql)
```

The above is untested

Answer (score 0):

I typically write it with a for loop, but you have to remember that with each loop you need a comma, unless it's the last loop.

I prefer to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE name IN (
{% for v in value_list %}
  "{{v}}"{{ ',' if not loop.last else ''}}
{% endfor %}
)
```

However, if all you're doing is joining together a list, you have a shorter way to write the jinja, like this:

```
{{ value_list |join(',') }}
```

This doesn't work in this situation because you need to wrap the value with quotation marks as well, but it's a handy one to know, because it is the most concise way to write it and it's very helpful when you're listing columns, etc.